# TypeError: 'TensorBoard' object is not callable

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

Im new on python and work on Spyder3 and trying to work with Keras and Tensorflow.
My problem is Im not able to open a tensorBoard window...

this is my code...

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
...
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(25, activation='relu', input_dim=4)) # premier layer a 25 noeud
model.add(Dense(320, activation='softmax'))
adm = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adm, metrics=['accuracy'])

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='./resultats/run_test', histogram_freq=1,
                          write_graph=True, write_images=False)
tensorboard.set_model(model) 
tensorboard(log_dir='./resultats/run_test')

hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=0.2, shuffle=True, epochs=20, batch_size=128, callbacks =[tensorboard] )
```

All work great until I add tensorBoard lines... 
Thank for your help

Comment: Like the error says, you can't call `tensorboard` like you do in the second-from-last line. Did you mean just `tensorboard.log_dir='./resultats/run_test'`? Why do you have that line at all, given you already passed `log_dir` when you created the instance two lines previously?

Comment: I agree, not usefull the second time, I try so much thing base on exemple see on the web.... forget to remove this one...

Comment: removing this line make tensorflow work but tensorBoard stay invisible...